# OpenCV Mac Linking g++?

Tags: macos, opencv, linker, g++

I've installed OpenCV by using Macports in Mac (Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 ). I've got the files in

> /opt/local/include/
> /opt/local/lib/

Now I want to test it. In the terminal, I did

> g++ main.cpp -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/
> -llibopencv_highgui.2.4.8 -llibopencv_core.2.4.8

This is what I got.

> ld: library not found for -llibopencv_highgui.2.4.8 collect2: ld
>
> returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem

> g++ main.cpp -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/
>   -lopencv_highgui.2.4.8 -lopencv_core.2.4.8

I removed lib from libopencv_core.2.4.8 and libopencv_highgui.2.4.8